# Trigger custom events on Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

can you tell me how to trigger custom events on Socket.io to be able to manage not just it's own like `io.sockets.on('connection', ...)`
But my custom `io.sockets.on('session:reload', ...)`

In older versions you could make it this way: `io.sockets.$emit("session:reload", sid);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `socket.emit`. See the [docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The OP got it right, it's just the method name that has changed. Thus, the answer need not contain much more.

Comment: Agree with @RobertRossmann. There's not much to talk when we just need to explain a method name.